# How many ways to reach point?

Tags: combinatorics

You're sitting at coordinates `(0,0)` and have 3 options:

1. Go up diagonally eg: `(0,0) -> (1,1)`
2. Go straight 1 step eg: `(0,0) -> (1,0)`
3. Go down diagonally eg: `(2,2) -> (3,1)`

You want to reach (p,0) and you're not allowed to go under 0 (Eg, you can only walk on >= 0 coordinates) and you can only go up to a point h, in height.

How many ways can you reach the point (p, 0) from (0,0) given to constraints mentioned above ?

Comment: Infinitely many, since you can start at $(0,0)$ and go up to $(1,1)$ and back down to $(0,0)$ as often as you like.

Comment: Not sure the rules are clear, by the way.  Does move $2$ also allow $(0,0)\mapsto (0,1)$ or can you only use $2$ to move up? And can you go from $(1,0)\mapsto (0,0)$ or is move $2$ only one way?  Also, did you mean to have some rule which excludes or restricts loops of the form I invoked?

Comment: "You want to reach (p,0)" - What is p?

Comment: I didn't say you can walk backwards. Also, p is a random point, consider p being 100 if it makes it easier for you to think about it.

Comment: @ErikCristianSeulean if you first do option 1 and than option 3, you go backwards.

Comment: What does that mean?  In my loop, I am only using the moves you provide explicitly,  I alternate moves $1$ and $3$ as often as I like.

Comment: That was a mistake, I updated the 3rd step

Comment: How is move $3$ consistent with the restriction on the positivity?  Or can I not invoke move $3$ from the origin? And what about my questions regarding move $2$?

Comment: You're moving forward either diagonally up, down or going straight 1 step at a time.

Comment: I changed the 3rd example to make sure it follows the rule of only positive coordinates.

Comment: So, every possible move increases the $x$ coordinate, yes?  So all paths must have length $p$, yes?

Comment: The sign requirement is inconvenient.  Say $p=2n$.  Then you can build many paths just using moves $1$ and $3$, but the sign restriction means that the number of those paths (no move $2$) is a [Catalan Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number).

Comment: Yes, every step increases so you will end up having at most p steps. The question is how many different paths are there ?

Comment: Why are you interested in this question? Do you want a closed form? A way to compute it efficiently? How efficiently is 'efficiently'?

Comment: No, all the paths will have exactly $p$ steps, yes?  There is no way to do it in less, unless I misunderstand the rules.  My comment regarding the Catalan numbers suggests that it will be difficult to get a convenient closed formula.  Recursive methods should be ok if you just want the number.

Comment: What is the source of this problem?

Comment: Yes, you're right there are exactly p steps. I am curious if somebody can come up with an equation that would solve this, instead of using recursion. I solved it using dynamic programming that's based on memorization for intermediary steps, although I'd like to see if there's something better then recursion.

Comment: I don't have a source for it, it's an extension that I thought about while solving a similar problem.

Comment: I doubt there will be anything better than recursion. But edit your post to provide the numerical solution for $1≤p≤10$, say.  Perhaps a pattern will emerge.

Comment: I'll do that. Thanks.

Comment: Using lulu's Catalan number observation above, we can certainly say that if $h$ is larger than $p$, then for $p = 2n$ the result is $\sum_{i = 0}^n \binom{2n}{2i} C_{n-i}$, and for $p = 2n + 1$ it is $\sum_{i = 0}^n \binom{2n+1}{2i+1} C_{n-i}$. You iterate over the number of times you take move 2, then count the number of placements of those moves 2, and then possible orderings of your moves 1 and 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the [Motzkin numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motzkin_number), OEIS [A001006](http://oeis.org/A001006). [Mathworld gives various expressions](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MotzkinNumber.html) which might be considered closed forms.